# Spring JPA Repositry Query creation with LIKE IN

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i'm trying to make a method in CrudRepository that will be able to give me a user with a JobType like one of these in my List of JobTypes. It should be something like a
`select * from User where JobType like '%oneOfThejobTypesInMyList%';`

Im trying the following but it wont work:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

  List<User> findByJobTypeLikeIn(List<String> jobType);

}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### JPA Criteria

To achieve `like` with `in` you have to use many `like` with `or`. You can do it with [`Criteria`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries) without `Repository`, for example:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

private List<User> findByLikeIn(String columnName, List<String> values) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> users = cq.from(User.class);

    values.stream()
        .map(v -> cb.like(users.get(columnName), "%" + v + "%"))
        .reduce(cb::or)
        .ifPresent(cq::where);

    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

And then use it:

```java
List<String> jobType = Arrays.asList("aa", "dap");
List<User> resultList = findByLikeIn("jobType", jobType);
```

It should create something like that:

```
select u from User u where u.jobType like '%jobType1%' or u.jobType like '%jobType2%';
```

#### Specification

Or above code you can apply in [specification](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification):

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
  
    static Specification<User> containing(String columnName,  List<String> values) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> values.stream()
                .map(v -> builder.like(root.get(columnName), "%" + v + "%"))
                .reduce(builder::or)
                .orElseGet(builder::conjunction);
    }
```

and using it like this:

```
List<String> jobType = Arrays.asList("aa", "dap");
List<User> resultList = userRepository.findAll(UserRepository.containing("jobType", jobType))
```

Comment: its a working solution yes, but what is, if i want a working query creation.

Comment: @user182410 other solution with Criteria

Comment: @user182410 and next with `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Comment: yes i'm trying to do that with a specifiction: `static Specification<Book> hasAuthor(String author) {
    return (book, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(book.get("author"), author);
}` , any idea how i can do that with my list ?

Comment: @user182410 do you want add `List<String> parameters` as next argument in `hasAuthor`? I do not know how `User` is related to `Book`?

Comment: @user182410 to sum up: does this answer to your main question? If no then you can provide additional info, if yes you can vote/approve it.

Comment: it's a working solution, not what I searched for but its working. thanks